# Inverting cursor colors in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, colors, cursor, inverse

I am learning QT programming and I wonder if there is an easy way to dynamically set cursor colors to be exact inverse of the colors under the cursor. I assume that the exact shape of the cursor is unknown during the compilation time and cursors can be overloaded through resources.

Just give me some general directions, no need to write a fully working code for me :)

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I suggest checking out this forum post on the Qt forums: [How to read a color of a pixel on a Widget?](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26241-How-to-read-a-color-of-a-pixel-on-a-Widget)

Here they explain that the best way to get the color at a certain pixel is to use the **QImage::pixel(const QPoint & position)** function. This function returns the color of the pixel at the given position. In your case you'll need to pass this function the mouse cursor's position.

To track the cursor's position use the **QCursor::pos()** function or if you need to track the position of the mouse at all moments you can override function in the QMouseEvent class such as **pos() or globalPos()** depending on your needs.

Now since you know the position of the cursor, the color of the cursor at a particular position, you simply need to create a new **QCursor** and set that cursor into the application using **QApplication::changeOverrideCursor(QCursor)** with your newly created cursor.

Some of these methods are costly in processing time, so I would advise you to think carefully about what your application is trying to achieve.

Hope that gives you a starting point. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is indeed a good start. The only thing which doesn't make it full solution is that the QImage::pixel returns the pixel pointed by the cursor and not the plurality of the pixels covered by cursor. I think QT supports different blending modes that can return the object of the shape of the Cursor with the colors of the final object. Inverting the colors should be trivial then.